# Was the magnetic field around a diamagnetic body measured or do we believe Faraday without proof?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

Diamagnetic materials are repelled by a magnetic field; an applied magnetic field creates an induced magnetic field in them in the opposite direction, causing a repulsive force. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism))

A sketch is attached to the explanation:
[image]

This corresponds to what Faraday found out around 1850 (shown in the sketch on the right):
[image]

Who and when measured the field to the right and left of the diamagnetic body? According to the sketches, the field is stronger than that of a ferromagnetic body. Has this been checked?

Comment: Surely if Faraday found it a good starting point would be to start looking at papers from that time? More recently, I think exact behaviour of magnetic fields near matter would have been thoroughly scrutinized by engineers designing MRIs, accelerators etc. That would be another place to look. Yet another place where this matters is magnetic hard-drive memory. So I guess, what I am saying, is that these days I would expect to see it in a IEEE journal  - but I never needed to check

Comment: @Cryo You never needed to check is the point I asked the question. Somebody has checked I think, but I do not found a source.

Comment: Engineers who design devices i listed abive check these things every day. Maybe not in the way you are thinking, it's 170 years too late for that, but indirectly and with extraordinary precision